# PHP scandir results: sort by folder-file, then alphabetically

Tags: php, sorting, scandir

PHP manual for [scandir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php): *By default, the sorted order is alphabetical in ascending order*.

I'm building a file browser (in Windows), so I want the addresses to be returned sorted by folder/file, then alphabetically in those subsets.

Example: Right now, I scan and output

```
Aardvark.txt
BarDir
BazDir
Dante.pdf
FooDir
```

and I want

```
BarDir
BazDir
FooDir
Aardvark.txt
Dante.pdf
```

**Other than a `usort` and `is_dir()` solution** (which I can figure out myself), is there a quick and efficient way to do this?

The ninja who wrote [this comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php#90628) is on the right track - is that the best way?

Comment: Post what you have figured out yourself, and then we can tell you if it can be improved.

Comment: @alex - I don't want to waste the time figuring it out myself, if there's a much more efficient way to do it that I'm missing.  I can just copy something from the manual if there's not a sweet answer out there.

Comment: My solution has been edited - you may want to edit your question to reflect that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does this give you what you want?

```
function readDir($path) {

    // Make sure we have a trailing slash and asterix
    $path = rtrim($path, '/') . '/*';

    $dirs = glob($path, GLOB_ONLYDIR);

    $files = glob($path);

    return array_unique(array_merge($dirs, $files));

}

$path = '/path/to/dir/';

readDir($path);
```

Note that you can't `glob('*.*')` for files because it picks up folders named `like.this`.

Comment: @alex - Yep that's a pretty elegant solution. How do you reckon it compares to a `usort`?

Comment: @Steve Well so long as your file system returns them in the order you want, it will be much quicker. I don't actually do any sorting. Did it work for you? **Edit** Made some edits. Let me know if it works for you (works for me on my tests).

Comment: @alex - With a few tweaks, finalizing now.  For example, `$filepath = 'path/to/dir/*';`.  Will update question w/ finalized code when working.

Comment: @alex cheers and +1 also for a great new function, didn't know about `blob` before.

Comment: @Steve I think you mean glob. Blob doesn't do anything. (Although it should.)

Comment: @Jeff Davis - yep, just too excited to type properly :)

Comment: @Jef Davis Haha. `blob()` indeed does need to be in PHP.

Comment: @alex - made another small change for more efficiency if you're interested: `$files = glob($filepath.'.*')` will only get the files, removing the need for `array_unique` and/or `array_diff`, jumping straight to `array_merge`.

Comment: @Steve It doesn't work the same, as I can name my folder `something.something` (and it was returned via `*.*`). You will get that folder twice in your array. :)

Answer (score 4):

Please try this. A simple function to sort the PHP *scandir* results by files and folders (directories):

```
function sort_dir_files($dir)
{
        $sortedData = array();
        foreach(scandir($dir) as $file)
        {
                if(is_file($dir.'/'.$file))
                        array_push($sortedData, $file);
                else
                        array_unshift($sortedData, $file);
        }
        return $sortedData;
}
```

Comment: Better than above solution, which "didn't work on my machine" :-).

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the party but I like to offer my solution with `readdir()` rather than with `glob()`. What I was missing from the solution is a recursive version of your solution. But with readdir it's faster than with glob.

So with glob it would look like this:

```
function myglobdir($path, $level = 0) {
    $dirs   = glob($path.'/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR);
    $files  = glob($path.'/*');
    $all2   = array_unique(array_merge($dirs, $files));
    $filter = array($path.'/Thumbs.db');
    $all    = array_diff($all2,$filter);

    foreach ($all as $target){
        echo "$target<br />";
        if(is_dir("$target")){
            myglobdir($target, ($level+1));
        }
    }
}
```

And this one is with readdir but has basically the same output:

```
function myreaddir($target, $level = 0){
    $ignore = array("cgi-bin", ".", "..", "Thumbs.db");
    $dirs = array();
    $files = array();

    if(is_dir($target)){
        if($dir = opendir($target)){
            while (($file = readdir($dir)) !== false){
                if(!in_array($file, $ignore)){
                    if(is_dir("$target/$file")){
                        array_push($dirs, "$target/$file");
                    }
                    else{
                        array_push($files, "$target/$file");
                    }

                }
            }

            //Sort
            sort($dirs);
            sort($files);
            $all = array_unique(array_merge($dirs, $files));

            foreach ($all as $value){
                echo "$value<br />";
                if(is_dir($value)){
                    myreaddir($value, ($level+1));
                }
            }
        }
        closedir($dir);
    }

}
```

I hope someone might find this useful.